# Any other fumarolic ice caves in the literature?

Tags: volcanology, glaciology

I study the fumarolic ice caves of Erebus Volcano, and am looking for published research on similar sorts of caves. My criteria for a "fumarolic ice cave" are that it must be:

- A gas-filled void space in a snowpack large enough to fit humans
- Present because of geothermal or volcanic heat
- Not primarily present because of a flow of water

So far, these are the fumarolic ice caves I know of:

- The [fumarolic ice caves](http://dx.doi.org/10.1029/2011GL048272) of Mt. Erebus, Antarctica
- [The crater firn caves](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/S0377-0273%2899%2900180-8) of Mt. Rainier, USA
- [Crater firn caves](http://www.caves.org/pub/journal/PDF/V60/V60N1-Anderson.pdf) of Mt. St. Helens, USA
- [Caves in Mt. Baker's Sherman Crater](http://www.oregongeology.org/pubs/og/OBv40n08.pdf), USA
- Small fumarolic ice cave on Villarrica volcano, Chile (no reference, I've just been in it)

I imagine there are probably hundreds more and these things are common on glaciated volcanoes. I'd be particularly interested in references for Kamchatka and Iceland where I suspect I may not be able to find information because of the language barrier.

Note that I am not asking about rock-hosted caves with a permanent ice mass.

Comment: Literally, the answer to your title question likely *no*.  I think this question is difficult to answer.  You already state there may be hundreds.  What kind of answer are you looking for?

Comment: True, the answer was obviously "no," so I just edited the title. I'm looking for an answer that includes a list of the ones I'm missing, or a reference to such a list. This might be a good community wiki question I guess. Can we do that?

Comment: This just seems to be too broad of a question. As you say, there's *hundreds* of these, and probably no well defined list. So then it turns into a list question... [this meta question](http://meta.earthscience.stackexchange.com/questions/11/are-list-questions-welcome) talks about list questions.

Comment: I think it's not broad at all -- it's a very specific, rare type of geological phenomenon and I think I've defined it well. It certainly is a list question and I wasn't aware of the unresolved debate over list questions.

Comment: I wonder if it's too *specific*. Wikipedia wouldn't host a list of these caves for that reason. To my mind, it's something akin to asking "what are all the large roundabouts with plants on the in the US"?

Comment: So, it's interesting to note that no one answered this question. I actually think the fact of the matter is that I was wrong to guess there are hundreds, and there are only a few of these in existence. I still don't know if there ARE any in Iceland or Kamchatka. Can anyone suggest a way to find out, since apparently this is the wrong venue?